# Doing a standard integral with complex numbers instead of using a trigonometric substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, indefinite-integrals

I was looking at some integrals to do with trigonometric substitutions and I stumbled across this one

$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx$$

I know you can do it with a regular trigonometric substitution or just use a hyperbolic substitution but I was wondering if you can do it the following way.

$$
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}} dx
 = \int \frac{\cos \theta}{\sqrt{-\cos^2\theta}}d\theta
 = \int \frac{1}{i}d\theta
 = \frac{1}{i}\arcsin x,
$$
where the $x=\sin \theta$ substitution was used. Could anybody please explain to me why I don't get the same result as one would get if a hyperbolic or other trigonometric substitution was used?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx=\text{arcosh}(x)+C=\pm i\arccos(x)+C$$ $$=\pm i\left(\frac\pi2-\arcsin(x)\right)+C=\mp i\arcsin(x)+\left(C\pm i\frac\pi2\right)$$ $$=\pm\frac1i\arcsin(x)+D$$

Comment: @mr_e_man thanks for the reposnse. Could you please clarify or link the source for where $\text{arccosh (x)} = +/- \arccos (x)$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: $$\cosh(\pm i\theta)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(\pm i\theta)^{2k}}{(2k)!}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{\theta^{2k}}{(2k)!}=\cos(\theta)$$

Answer (score 2):

To keep you original integral real you require
$$
x^2 \gt 1
$$
If you let $$ x=\sin \theta$$ then for real $\theta$ it must be true that
$$
-1 \le x \le 1 \Rightarrow x^2 \le 1
$$

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.  I have a question. Why is $x^2>1$ required? Why can't you consider the case for $x^2<1$ and then consider the real part of the integral? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are multiple things to think about if integrating a complex valued function. You need to consider carefully the region your function is defined on, the path of integration and things such as the singularity in the integrand at $x=1$. e.g. $\frac{1}{z}$ has a singularity (pole) at the origin $\int \frac{1}{z}dz$  produces different results for closed loops depending whether or not the loop encloses that singularity.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. I just want to make sure I am understanding this correctly. The reason this approach can not be used for x>1 is that you will go from real to complex variables. I think I understand that. However, why can't one integrate, for example, from 2 to infinity with x beeing a complex number and then taking the real part to get the same answer as one would get with a hyperbolic substitution? Thanks in advance.